# Root causes for failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Tags: linux, ssd

On a brand new Intel NUC (10th gen) with brand new Samsung SSD 860 EVO 250GB RVT04B6Q that SSD yields some WRITE FPDMA QUEUED command failures such as this one:

```
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x60 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: cmd 61/40:28:00:d7:31/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 32768 out 
                          res 40/00:28:00:d7:31/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: cmd 61/20:30:40:d7:31/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 16384 out 
                          res 40/00:28:00:d7:31/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov 28 21:25:26  ata3: hard resetting link
Nov 28 21:25:27  ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300) 
Nov 28 21:25:27  ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
Nov 28 21:25:27  ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
Nov 28 21:25:27  ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 28 21:25:27  ata3: EH complete
Nov 28 21:25:27  ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

These happen periodically in the order of 20 per day, while only relatively little IO happens. So far the Btrfs fileystem hasn't complained about checksum errors.

So is this just Samsung selling SSDs with poor quality assurance, possibly a bad cable or is a more systematic issue - such as Samsung not implementing commands in a standard conforming way, in its firmware?

---

**Update 2020-01-09**:

A brand new replacement Samsung SSD (same model) yields the [same errors](https://gist.github.com/gsauthof/01673e6c9134eac4a58086cf678d093a) in that NUC. And with each burst of such errors the CRC_ERROR_COUNT SMART counter is incremented by one.

Opening the NUC shows that the SATA cable is folded (cf. bottom left corner):

[image: NUC folded SATA cable]

Perhaps this sharp fold was deliberately applied by Intel during production. But it seems that it's unnecessary. Also if it was applied deliberately, why is there just one fold? I mean, two would make more sense then for symmetry (since the SSD is on top of the main board, i.e. integrated in the top cover). Also, is the 45 degree orientation of the fold optimal? I'm not an electrical engineer thus all this is perhaps completely irrelevant to this problem.

A good way to reproduce this error is to use `fio`. I mean it also happens during normal usage (e.g. when upgrading/installing packges), but with fio it's easier to reproduce. Example:

```
fio --rw=randrw --name=lol --bs=128k --direct=1 --filename=/dev/nvme0n1 \
    --numjobs=1 --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --refill_buffers
```

If you run this - say - 2 times in a row and you don't see this error than this is a pretty good indication that your hardware is good and doesn't have this issue.

Comment: What does `smartctl -a` return?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani https://gist.github.com/gsauthof/76af913c0d03a128c93f809a96904535 - perhaps the CRC_ERROR_Count or POR_Recovery_Count look interesting?

Comment: FWIW, I have a similar NUC and have the same cable fold. Also the same errors on a Seagate Firecuda SSHD. I'd been wondering if I'd managed to crimp the cable somehow by trapping it in the case .. but maybe that's less likely if you've got it too...

Comment: had to make some small changes to that to run in Mint: `sudo fio --rw=randrw --name=lol --bs=128k --filename=/dev/nvme0n1     --numjobs=1 --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --refill_buffers --size=128k`

Answer (score 7):

So I might be wrong here but I don't have enough rep to comment, so here's my 2cents.

I have a desktop with the same SSD, and get the exact same errors. It's due to a bug with the AMD SATA chipset & Samsung firmware - is it an AMD system? If so, you can disable NCQ with libata.force=noncq in the kernel parameters.

As you saw in the smart report, the CRC_ERROR_COUNT is (one?) of the parameters affected by this. It can either be caused by NCQ & this bug, or faulty SATA cables. So I'd try disabling NCQ first. This will hurt performance, though.

EDIT: Although, I do see some occurances of the problem with Intel controllers too: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203475#c14

Comment: It's an Intel NUC, so no AMD. Regarding disabling NCQ - since that system has another (NVMe) SSD - is it possible to just disable NCQ for a single drive?

Comment: PS: The SATA cable is included with the NUC barebone kit, i.e. it's kind of integrated with the so called SATA daughtercard which is part of the chassis. I haven't opened the chassis so far (since the SSDs/RAM were pre-installed by the vendor).

Comment: Since you're getting the error on ata3.00, you can disable it specifically for that port by using libata.force=3.00:noncq

Comment: FWIW, I've got a brand new replacement Samsung SATA SSD (same model+firmware) and it yields the same errors. Also, every time the exception occurs, the CRC_ERROR_COUNT is incremented by one (new drive was delivered with a zero count). Thus, it's really either a general incompatibility of that firmware/model or the cable/(one of the connectors) is faulty. I'm not 100 % sure whether that NUC-SATA cable even is field-replaceable.

Comment: Mind sharing which AMD bug you are referring to?  I ran in the same issue on my AMD server.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm hitting this same problem with Intel CPU + Intel chipset. According to above linked kernel bug the root cause is drive firmware freezing if NCQ is enabled and multiple TRIM/Discard commands are sent. Linux kernel previously assumed that ALL Samsung 8xx SSDs were broken this way (originally diagnosed with 840) but Samsung marketing department declared that later models "do work". It seems that marketing department didn't really know for sure and just claimed stuff they were hoping is real.

Comment: Note that it currently seems that the problem is related to SATA TRIM command so if you mount without `discard` flag *and* never ever run `fstrim`, the drive might keep going without errors even with NCQ enabled.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Apparently some users have the issue only with queued TRIM, some need to disable NCQ entirely. It depends if you have "SEND FPDMA QUEUED" (queued TRIM only) or "WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" (NCQ in general). https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203475#c15 Me personally, I get the latter, and the only fix is to disable NCQ entirely via kernel command line. (Samsung 860 EVO + AMD FX 970 chipset)

Comment: I have an old system with Intel H77 chipset and Samsung 860 EVO drive and I get "WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" error approximately once every two months. I'd say it's not related to the chipset but 860 EVO is just broken because the same system works just fine with other drives using NCQ. The exact trigger conditions are not fully understood but it seems to be related to some combination of multiple commands in NCQ queue.

Comment: Note that you can disable NCQ for individual devices with `echo 1 > /sys/block/sd?/device/queue_depth` so if you have multiple drives (like I do) you don't need to disable NCQ for the whole system.

Comment: Digging around with the error message hints that it could be that some SATA devices / chipsets are very sensitive to static discharge: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=549981#c62 – however, the system I'm experiencing the problem is fully grounded to known good earth connection.

Comment: Yes, I disable it individually with the libata parameter for a specific drive. It is strange how it affects AMD and Intel systems. I should try this drive in a different system, that's an interesting point about static

Comment: I've a mature (alright, *ancient*) AMD processor desktop machine and a new (to me) 1TB drive that fitted a few months back as a 5th drive (the machine triple boots and I am contemplating a 4th OS) has been given me these sort of errors often enough to actually cause crashes {I had a swap partition on it}. I am hoping that this tweak will be enough to stop it...

Comment: I got my system stable after having random issues with SATA drives by setting manual voltages on the motherboard in BIOS. I was monitoring the voltages with `sensors` before the change at it appeared that the BIOS firmware dropped voltages really low during C1E...C6 sleep states and the problems seemed to happen mostly during idling so I guess those were related. Since increasing the idle voltages the system has been totally stable and not a single error has happened since. The motherboard is old enough so I don't expect to see firmware fix ever.